# phpMyAdmin explanation of errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In v4.5.5.1 of phpMyAdmin I'm running the following MySQL code;

```
SELECT Date, DOW, Week, Year, logdate, Month, monum, netID, Logins, 
       creds, newb, netCnt, TOD, netCnt, activity
  FROM (SELECT logdate
              ,activity
              ,DATE( logdate )                      AS Date
              ,DAYOFWEEK( logdate )         AS DOW
              ,WEEK( logdate,0 )              AS Week
              ,YEAR( logdate )              AS Year
              ,DATE_FORMAT( logdate, '%M' )         AS Month
              ,DATE_FORMAT( logdate, '%m' )     AS monum
              ,CONVERT( netID,UNSIGNED INTEGER )    AS netID
              ,COUNT( callsign )                    AS Logins
              ,COUNT( IF(creds <> '',1,NULL) )  AS creds
              ,COUNT( IF(comments LIKE '%first log in%',1,NULL) ) AS newb
              ,count( DISTINCT netID )      AS netCnt
              ,SUM(  DISTINCT netID)            AS allCnt
              ,SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(timeonduty) )       AS TOD
         FROM NetLog
        WHERE netID <> 0 
          AND activity NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
          AND netcall LIKE '%W0KCN%'
          AND substr(logdate,1,4) = 2017
    GROUP BY Month, netID WITH ROLLUP ) AS t 
    ORDER BY t.logdate , logins
```

It runs just fine and returns everything I need but...
I get three errors on line 3 at 'FROM (SELECT logdate'

[image: Three errors]

I also get five errors at line 23 'GROUP BY Month, netID WITH ROLLUP ) AS t'...

[image: Five errors]

What do these mean and should I resolve them and of course how do I resolve them?

Comment: There are no syntax errors in that SQL. I just tested it in my local MySQL 5.6 instance and it got past syntax parsing without error (it then did error because I don't have your Netlog table, but syntax parsing comes first). I suppose phpMyAdmin could have an incomplete understanding of advanced SQL, but that seems pretty lame. Is there a way to turn off the syntax checking?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not as robust a tool as something like [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) so if you have the option of using Workbench, stick with that.

Comment: This issue appears to be simply an out-dated version of software and not a true code problem. This issue is resolved by updating the software in question to a more recent edition.

Comment: I'm glad to hear there are no issues with the code. Like I indicated it runs and gives me the output (almost) that I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state:

> In v4.5.5.1

PHPMyAdmin current version is 4.7.7, [you can get it here](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/).

I have run your query in my version of 4.7.3 and this doesn't show these errors when run.

The issue is that you version of 4.5.5 was released in 2015 and so is pretty old... bugs get fixed, codes get improved, PHPMyAdmin has always trailed a little with dealing with advanced SQL syntax checking.

I would second the comment [stated by tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232069/phpmyadmin-explanation-of-errors/48233029#comment83446745_48232069) that

> phpMyAdmin is not as robust a tool as something like [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) so if you have the option of using Workbench